# how to align a text view in a listView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am not getting proper alignment even though I constrained the textviews.My text is running over the other text which looks messy.
[Here is the screenshot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g98fq.png).
I want it to align properly even if the text goes some large.Please suggest some ways to do that.
Here is the code for my layout-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="7.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:maxWidth="135dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/date"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/magnitude"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="Rio de Janerio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.967"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/magnitude"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="May 20,2016" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[The New layout that I want is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK2SH.png)

Comment: how would you like it to be?

Comment: Hey @meditat I have added the new layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re created your layout please use below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum=".6"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:text="7.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:text="Rio de Janerio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="May 20,2016" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library to fit text
build gradle file(app):

```
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
```

Usage in layout

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/question_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Post samething"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/icons"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
                />
```

You can read more from this [link](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with constraint layout you can use the baseline of the text view for this purpose

> **Baseline alignment**
>   Align the text baseline of a view to the text baseline of another view.

See the related section in the documentation in order to learn how to use the baseline allinment
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#baseline